# how do I display an array of data using a custom pipe in angular 2?

Tags: angular2-forms

I need to display data on the client side using a custom pipe in Angular 2.
 
I want to display the data in a table.
The data is stored as an array on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would serialize your model to json and serve your data at a url endpoint like 
`your.domain.com/api/model`.

Then you can use Angular 2's Http service to request the JSON. 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data.

Displaying the data would involve using an ngFor on table rows.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html#!#ngFor